# How do i get flame wings on terraria

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I really need help here I have a mythril anvil and adamanite forge just in case I have pretty much all crafting stations so... Help?

Comment: You have 20 Souls of Flight and 1 Fire Feather?

Answer (score 4):

After killing at least 1 mechanical boss in hardmode (The twins, Destroyer etc.), a mob called a [Red Devil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Red_Devil) will begin spawning in the underworld. These have a small chance (1.33%) to drop a Fire Feather. You also need 20 Souls of Flight which are dropped by Wyverns spawning in the sky.

Combining a Fire Feather with 20 souls of flight at your mythril anvil will give you the Flame wings.

Comment: More generally: The Guide is your friend (even though you killed him). If you know about Flame Wings, you know about wings. If you know about wings, you probably know about Souls of Flight and their use in wings. So ask the Guide what you can craft with them, and the recipe would show up right there.

Comment: @MikeKellogg the wiki is a better friend, and dies less often